React Native- TextInput horizontal padding diferent android and ios
IOS

ANDROID

Android must look like iOS
textInput: {
height: '100%',
fontSize: 15,
fontFamily:
...padding(0, 'horizontal'),
},
This is the text input style
  <RNTextInput
    ref={ref}
    style={[
      baseStyles.textInput,
      inputStyle,
    ]}
    placeholderTextColor={
      baseStyles.placeholder
        .color
    }
    editable={!disabled}
    onKeyPress={event => {
      onKeyDown &&
        onKeyDown(event);
      onKeyUp && onKeyUp(event);
    }}
    {...remainingTextInputProps}
  />
  <Text>%</Text>

